# Gitlab ci can't run more than 2 ssh commands

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to deploy my app with docker from gitlab using it's ci. I have configured gitlab-ci as follow (it's simplified, docker build and push to registy is done in eariel steps but for readability I'll skip it)

```
image: docker:stable

services:
  - postgres:latest
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

run_develop_container:
  stage: deploy
  image: kroniak/ssh-client
  before_script:
    - which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    - ssh-keyscan -H $DEVELOP_SERVER >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  script:
    - scp docker-compose-develop.yml $SSH_DEPLOY_USER@$DEVELOP_SERVER:~/docker-compose.yml
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SSH_DEPLOY_USER@$DEVELOP_SERVER "docker login -u $DOCKER_USER_ID -p $DOCKER_USER_PASSWORD"
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SSH_DEPLOY_USER@$DEVELOP_SERVER "docker-compose -p app-name down --remove-orphans"
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SSH_DEPLOY_USER@$DEVELOP_SERVER "docker-compose -p app-name pull && docker-compose -p app-name up -d"
  only:
    - setup_deploy_process
```

And the output from pipeline looks like this

```
... some common things ...
$ which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 12
$ echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
Identity added: (stdin) ((stdin))
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ [[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
$ ssh-keyscan -H $DEVELOP_SERVER >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
# some_data_with_develop_server_ip
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
$ scp docker-compose-develop.yml $SSH_DEPLOY_USER@$DEVELOP_SERVER:~/docker-compose.yml
$ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SSH_DEPLOY_USER@$DEVELOP_SERVER "docker login -u $DOCKER_USER_ID -p $DOCKER_USER_PASSWORD"
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Login Succeeded
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/runner/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

$ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SSH_DEPLOY_USER@$DEVELOP_SERVER "docker-compose -p app-name down --remove-orphans"
ssh: connect to host 159.89.24.62 port 22: Connection refused
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Now, for me it looks that ssh is configured properly since script is able to connect to scp docker-compose and login into registry.

As develop server I have a one-click docker droplet from DigitalOcean, is it possible that it can't handle this traffic? Maybe I should wait a moment till calling next ssh command? I'm totally lost since this is a pretty basic configuration and I'm not able to find any other so I'll be really greatful for any hint, thanks!

Comment: Yup, after moving all of commands into one combined which requires only one ssh connection it's started to working. But why? Isn't it possible to make many ssh connection and call only one commend each time?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a config somewhere in DO throttling ssh to prevent multiple, successive connections? (this might be investigated by passing at least one `-v` flag to the `ssh` command…)

In any case, a solution could be to merge your ssh commands in a single one.

For example could you try something like this?

```
- ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no …@… "docker login … && docker-compose …"
```

Otherwise, assuming you have a bash script somewhere in your repo, you could also use a pipe in order to run this script remotely, for example:

```
- cat some_script.sh | ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no …@… "bash --login"
```

Comment: Thanks, I did just that and indeed it helped. Acctually I also tried to wait between each ssh for a couple of seconds and this also seemed to help. Is ssh connection open for whole time of command execution? And if so is it possible to tell gitlab-ci to wait exactly for the end of this execution?

Comment: Sure: this is what's happens by default.

Comment: @kebie on second thought it seemed the `bash --login -c "…"` phrasing I had suggested in my answer was not working due to command quoting; as a matter of fact you can just run `ssh [options] …@… "command1 && command2"` (or alternatively use a pipe, see the last part of my updated answer)

Comment: Do you know maybe how can I change settings to allow multiple connections? Merging commands with `&&` is working as expected but it's kind of hard to work with this limitation. I've changed `MaxSessions` parameter in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` but the problem still occurs.